# How to perform multiple $lookup for array mongodb aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

How can i perform `$lookup` in aggregate (mongodb) for an array

```
{
     messages: [{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bfc43f2bbc4176ecc1c5f83"),
            "text" : "text1",
            "sender" : {
                    "id" : "36046fc2e70dd508a0bf1f36fd2daa20"
            }
         }, {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bfc43f2bbc4176ecc1c5f83"),
            "text" : "text2",
            "sender" : {
                    "id" : "36046fc2e70dd508a0bf1f36fd2daa22"
            }
    }],
    "filed1": { ... },
    "filed2": { ... }
}
```

how can i do a `$lookup` for sender id from accounts collection?

#### tried:

```
...
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "accounts",
          localField: "messages.sender.id",
          foreignField: "id",
          as: "messages.sender.user"
        }
      }
...
```

Comment: Does the answer works for you?

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to push the whole doc to result ($group) return messages only because push $message returns messages only,

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. But if the below answer works for you then please accept it and If you have any further doubts then please ask a new question in separate thread.

Comment: I can't create new thread but its ok, thank you :)

Comment: *I can't create new thread but its ok* Why? I will surely help you.

Comment: _Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account_, all what i want is to return the original doc (`$$ROOT`) to the result,

Comment: Pushing all the document in a single array in a `$group` stage is not a good job. It will breach the [BSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size) limit of 16 MB. I have upvoted your one question try now to ask.

Comment: still same message, and is there any other way to return origianl doc?
for example 

```
{
  messages : [...],
  other_filed: "data"
} 
```
return that filed with the result

Comment: I cannot understand. Please edit your question and put the whole explanation to it.

Comment: ok cool!!!. I have updated the answer. Use `$first` for the other fields ;-)

Comment: Thank you again, but the function that im looking for is that not to know what i'm pushing for example there is 15 filed, _is there a way to push them automatically_?

Comment: You need to use `$facet` aggregation for that. Try to google it and refer.

Comment: Ok, Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$messages" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "accounts",
    "localField": "messages.sender.id",
    "foreignField": "id",
    "as": "messages.sender.user"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$messages.sender.user" }
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "messages": { "$push": "$messages" },
    "filed1": { "$first": "$filed1" },
    "filed2": { "$first": "$filed2" }
  }}
])
```